# How to pass variables from one container movie clip to a child movie child?

Tags: flash

My question is not like the one I read because the context is different:

Let's say instead of embedding a flash inside an html page with some flashvars, I want to embed it inside another flash or flex. How to set the flashvars in this case (using ActionScript 3) ?

So how to embed Flash in another flash and set same variables as it was embedded in html by passing querystring or flashvars

I have searched all over the Internet and incredibly nobody seems to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to flashvars you can send variables and values as arguments on the URL of the swf file, so something like this:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("sub.swf?variable=value"));
```

In the sub swf you can access the URL arguments the same way you would access flashvars, from the loaderInfo.parameters.